# Redirect user to a specific page

Tags: 8, uri

I'm new to drupal. And I have a project that has a search block on the home page that redirects the user to a page based on the user search terms. Everything works fine but I have a FAQ page that includes all Questions and a search block and tags `https://example.com/faq?keys=drupal&tags=All`. 
The issue is when users search for terms on the home page, it redirects the user to the question node `https://example.com/faq/53335` not the FAQ page and show the user question.

How can I fix that, should I create an alter function to check if it's FAQ page so redirect the user to that page and show him the asked question?

Update:
the scenario is when user search for a term on the home page, the user will be redirected to another page that shows all search results as a list. some of the results belong to the faq page while others not. when the user clicks on the question, it'll redirect to the question node `https://example.com/faq/53335`, not the faq page 
 `https://example.com/faq?keys=drupal&tags=All`

Is the faq page configured to redirect the user to the answer when there is only one answer? No, even if there is only one answer, the user will redirect to the page that shows all result. and from this page, he can click on the question.

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario a bit more? Does the search block on the home page submit to the faq page? Is the faq page configured to redirect the user to the answer when there is only one answer?

Comment: @anoopjohn Please check my updated question.

Comment: Add a filter for FAQ titles as exposed form to your FAQ view.

Comment: Looks like leymannx understood your question. I am still unable to understand what your issue is.

Comment: Did you fix the problem? @IDI